# Meteor cannot configure login (accounts-google, etc...)

Tags: javascript, meteor, oauth

I added the following packages:

accounts-password
accounts-ui
accounts-google
accounts-facebook
accounts-twitter

But when I click any of the three red button to configure google, facebook or twitter, the buttons does absolutely nothing, so I can't configure the app...

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz338.png)

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed it was a problem with my `iron router`, I didn't really understand it but removing `{{> yield}}` from my `main.html` solved my problem.

Cheers !